# App doesn't close, always remains in Suspended mode while usage of background task in c#/xaml windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, background-process

I am developing an app. Which uses live tiles with background task (as WinRT Component) as I want to updates tile with time trigger. I have noticed that if I set permission of lock screen to ON and let the background task run then app always remains in suspended mode after I close the app. So how can I kill the app and let the background task run on it's own ? I am following [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Tile-Update-every-minute-68dbbbff).

Comment: This is entirely by design, Store apps never close unless forced to by the user.

Comment: But the close gesture or alt+f4 closes the app not put it in suspended mode forever

Comment: this happens in regular WPF non 'metro' apps too sometimes

Answer (score 0):

You can forcefully close an app in a number of ways:

- Alt+F4
- Swipe the app from the top of the screen to the bottom
- Use the task manager

Answer (score 0):

You cannot programmatically kill your app (well you can if you introduce a `NullPointerException` (**DON'T DO THAT**) or if system memory requirement kicks in (system needs memory for other tasks so OS will kill your application.).

please read following article on Windows 8 application lifecycle.

[Application Lifecycle](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2012/11/29/31-days-of-windows-8-day-29-application-lifecycle/)

Comment: I don't want to kill an app. See, when user close the app as close gesture or alt+f4 then the app won't be in task manager. But in my case my app doesn't close bt remains suspended mode in task manager.

Comment: I am not sure why that's happening, I tried closing my app with alt+f4 and it closed (stayed in task manager for 30 sec and then disappeared).